# How can I use a spinner with a button to redirect the app to other activites

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I am trying to make my first interactive app and its my first time using a spinner for a drop down menu. What I want is the user to select an item from the dropdown menu and for that to be stored in a variable so that when the button is clicked they are redirected to the proper page this is what I have in the main file.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.positonSpinner);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,parent.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String Text = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

public void goOnClick (View v)
{
    Button go = (Button)v;
    if (Text == "Student" )
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,StudentUser.class));
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AdminUser.class) );
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your activity is incomplete, but there is nothing wrong with it. What isn't working exactly?

Comment: Your question indicates that you know what to do but haven't tried actually doing it. Such questions tend to be downvoted and deleted on stackoverflow, because people might think you are being lazy. Please, tell people what exactly you failed to do next time. "stored in a varible" is a pretty basic thing to do. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question contains your answer. Store the value from the spinner in some instance variable and choose your "proper page" accordingly. "redirected to the proper page" probably means you are going to have to create some other `Activity` than `LoginActivity` and pass its class to the `Intent`.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String spinnerValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.positonSpinner);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
            spinnerValue = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.THE_BUTTON_YOU_HAVE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null == spinnerValue) {
                // Tell the user to choose something
                return;
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(
                v.getContext(),
                spinnerValue == "Student" ? StudentActivity.class : AdminActivity.class
            ));    
        }
    });
}
}
```